# setVisibility не работает

Tags: java, android, view

Почему код `findViewById(R.id.connectServer).setVisibility(View.GONE);` не скрывает View, но если запустить  код `System.out.println(findViewById(R.id.connectServer).getVisibility()==View.GONE);`  то он выводит `true`
Подскажите пожалуйста, почему так происходит?

```
package абсолютно.секретно;
import *;
public class abc extends AppCompatActivity {
    @SuppressLint({"StaticFieldLeak", "SetTextI18n"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.abc);
new AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer>(){
                @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
                @Override
                protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... voids) {
                    //...
publishProgress();
                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
findViewById(R.id.connectServer).setVisibility(View.GONE);
findViewById(R.id.abc).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}.execute();
}
}
```

Код разметки:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <include android:id="@+id/abc" layout="@layout/activity_abc"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/connectServer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".client_wifi">
            <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/..."
                />
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/code"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/..."
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="italic|bold"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

*P.S. connectServer это FrameLayout*

Comment: А можно код разметки и сам код?

Comment: Всё, выложил :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробуйте сначала присвоить переменную, а затем установить видимость

```
FrameLayout CS;
CS = findViewById(R.id.connectServer);
CS.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Нет, не работает

Comment: Очень странно...

Comment: Попробуйте вынести установку видимости за asynctask, в основную функцию

Comment: Если вынести, то работает. Но мне надо в onProgressUpdate(), и у этой функции вроде есть доступ к viewам

Comment: onPreExecute() – выполняется перед doInBackground(). Имеет доступ к UI
onPostExecute() – выполняется после doInBackground() (может не вызываться, если AsyncTask был отменен). Имеет доступ к UI. Используйте его для обновления пользовательского интерфейса, как только ваша фоновая задача завершена. Данный обработчик при вызове синхронизируется с потоком GUI, поэтому внутри него вы можете безопасно изменять элементы пользовательского интерфейса.

Comment: Другие методы не имеют доступа к ui

Comment: Ваш ответ (считая ваши комментарии к ответу) вредный. Из [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)): `protected void onProgressUpdate (Progress... values)
Выполняется в потоке пользовательского интерфейса после publishProgress(Progress...)`. Вы вводите в заблуждение других участников сообщества. Считаю, что единственная проблема в отмене задачи: `onProgressUpdate(Progress...) не будет вызываться, если задача была отменена` ([документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#publishProgress(Progress...)))

Comment: Считайте, ваше право. Я взял информацию из учеников